# select nearest date if not find in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hello all i have a problem which is like:

**Problem:** I have an array of dates and some of the dates are missing for example. `['10-Mar-2017','11-Mar-2017','12-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017','15-Mar-2017','16-Mar-2017','17-Mar-2017','19-Mar-2017','23-Mar-2017','25-Mar-2017','26-Mar-2017','27-Mar-2017']`.

Now i want to highlight the dates in my front end which is working smoothly, But it works only if my range is available in the array. For example i select to highlight `13-Mar-2017` This did not work. 
So i thought if i take a nearest date like if `13` is not available it should highlight `14-Mar-2017`. This is what i tried.

**Tried Solution:**

```
min_date = getFormattedDate(dates.min);
max_date = getFormattedDate(dates.max);
temp_date=new Date(min_date);

for (index=0; index < graphData.graph_data.length; index++){
  date = new Date(getFormattedDate(graphData.graph_data[index].date));

  if (temp_date == date) {
    min_date=getFormattedDate(temp_date);

  } else {
    temp_date = (new Date(temp_date).addDays(1));
  }
}
```

`getFormattedDate` is my function which passed me the string after making the desire output format date.

Any solution ?

Comment: Which dates do you want to highlight?

Comment: @xs0 actually it doesnot matter but lets suppose i want to get the dates `13-Mar-2017 to 17-Mar-2017` as `13-Mar-2017` is not available it should select  `14-Mar-2017`

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nearest-date

Comment: @jkordas i dont want to use the library really.

Comment: You can calculate dates 'distance' with difference of their's getTime functions result. Choose the smallest one.

Comment: @jkordas did not understand your comment

Comment: You can iterate over your array of dates and calculate dates[i].getTime() - selectedDate.getTime(), the date for which this result is closest to zero wins.

Comment: Since *temp_date* and *date* are Date objects, then `temp_date == date` will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getTime() to get a number that represents number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 and compare the distance between two dates. like this:

```js
var dates = ['10-Mar-2017','11-Mar-2017','12-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017','15-Mar-2017','16-Mar-2017','17-Mar-2017','19-Mar-2017','23-Mar-2017','25-Mar-2017','26-Mar-2017','27-Mar-2017'];

function getClosestDate(myDate, dates){
    var distances = [];
    var option = new Date(myDate);
    for(let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
    {
      distances[i] = { index: i, 
                       distance: Math.abs(new Date(dates[i]).getTime() -                                  option.getTime()),
                       value: new Date(dates[i]).getTime()
      };
    }

    distances.sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance);
    var smallestDistance = distances[0].distance;
    //now get the greater date in same distances
    distances = distances.filter((v) => v.distance == smallestDistance);
    distances.sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value);

    return dates[distances[0].index];
}
console.log(getClosestDate('13-Mar-2017', dates));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *temp_date* and *date* are Date objects:

```
temp_date == date
```

will always evaluate to false.

You've left out a lot of information on how you're parsing, formatting and incrementing dates so I've included trivial versions of those.

You can compare the strings as dates after parsing, but you shouldn't rely on the built-in parser. For missing dates, you seem to want to go to the next highest date, so the following does that. If you want the nearest date, you'll need a little more logic to go to next highest and next lowest, then pick the one you want.

The following searches for a matching date and if found, returns it. Otherwise, it looks for the next highest date. If it's beyond the range, it returns a message. You may want to include a lower bound as well.

This isn't a complete solution, just an example of how to go about it.

```js
// Setup functions to parse, format and increment Dates
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
  return this;
}

Date.prototype.formatDate = function(){
  var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');
  return ('0'+this.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + months[this.getMonth()] + '-' + this.getFullYear(); 
}

Date.parseF = function(s) {
  var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.split('-');
  return new Date(b[2], months.indexOf(b[1]), b[0]);
}

// Data
var dates = ['12-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017'];

// Get matching date or next highest
function getNearest(s, data) {
  // Set limits for search
  var min = Date.parseF(s);
  var max = Date.parseF(data[data.length - 1]);

  do {
    // Search for match
    var idx = data.indexOf(s);
    // If found, return s
    if (idx >= 0) return s;
    // Otherwise, increment date and search again
    min.addDays(1);
    s = min.formatDate();
  } while (min <= max)
  return 'Outside range';
}

// Tests
['12-Mar-2017','13-Mar-2017','14-Mar-2017','15-Mar-2017'].forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + ': ' + getNearest(s, dates));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for late replying your addDays function is same as mine sorry for not mentioning that.  Is there any solution that i dont have to split the date. ?

Comment: @fatpotato—you have to parse the string, you can use a library or write your own function, surely 2 lines of code isn't too much? Don't leave it to the built-in parser, it will let you down at an unexpected and inconvenient time.

Comment: i have done it with my own function and a flag to check the status of finding the date in the given array.